# Flyway spring boot + java, new local database created by hibernate but now migrate tries to apply migrations that already happened

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I initially created my project using hibernate to create tables like most people do, but then following recommendations I started using flyway to do db migrations.

Problem is I erased my entire local system including db and trying to spin it u again but I get conflicts of hibernate and flyway.

I'm using the java api by the way. So when I went to rebuild the database locally I turned on
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=${HIBERNATE_DDL:create}` just for the first run, then turned it to validate

So it built all the tables, but now when I try to launch the application it will try to run the first migration which is

`ALTER TABLE public.auth ADD COLUMN resent boolean`

which will cause an error on boot because that new column was added by hibernate

```
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "resent" of relation "auth" already exists
Location   : db/migration/V1__Add_Resent_To_Auth.sql (/Users/brian/code/slap/build/resources/main/db/migration/V1__Add_Resent_To_Auth.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE public.auth
    ADD COLUMN resent boolean
```

So how do I tell flyway that the current version is V9 and only run migrations after that. Shouldn't it just go look at the flyway_schema_history and see version 9 is the last entry then run migrations after that? I must be missing something

I tried doing this in my config to set the baseline version first

```
@Configuration
class FlyWay() {

    @Value("\${spring.datasource.url}")
    lateinit var url: String

    @Value("\${spring.datasource.username}")
    lateinit var username: String

    @Value("\${spring.datasource.password}")
    lateinit var password: String

    @Bean
    fun migrate() {
        val flyway = Flyway.configure().baselineVersion("9.0").dataSource(url, username, password).load()
        flyway.migrate()
    }
}
```

no such luck it still tries to run V1

I tried adding it to application.properties too
`spring.flyway.baselineVersion=9.0`
same error

Answer (score 2):

Scenario as I understood it:

- Tables already exist
- State of the tables corresponds to version "9.0"
- Flyway baseline version should be set once for the local test DB

It might be useful to set the version via command line, since it is to be applied to the test database only once and then the normal migration strategies are to be applied.

Documentation see: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/baseline

On macOS the Flyway command line client can be installed with `brew install flyway`.

**Instructions**

- make sure the table flyway_schema_history is deleted. Use your preferred SQL client:

```
   drop table flyway_schema_history;
```

- then set the baseline version using the Flyway command line client (this example uses a Postgres database):

```
   flyway -user=stephan -password= -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stephan -baselineVersion="9.0" -locations="src/main/resources/db/migration" baseline
```

- check in SQL client:

```
select version from flyway_schema_history ;
```

This should show now "9.0". After that, the Spring Boot application should behave as usual.

**Test**

[image: demo]

**Alternative**

For those people who prefer to do this with a Maven command:

- drop the table flyway_schema_history like shown above
- use the command `mvn flyway:baseline -Dflyway.baselineVersion="9.0"`  to set the baseline version

This requires a bit of configuration in the `pom.xml` file, e.g. if using a Postgres database:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stephan</url>
                <user>stephan</user>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.2.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    ...
```

**Test with Maven**

A quick test shows the same result.

[image: demo with maven]

Answer (score 1):

Why not export the SQL-script from your database (created by Hibernate) and add it as the first Flyway script into your application? It's the cleanest solution as Hibernate doesn't need to be started manually again when the application will run on other systems.

Comment: i looked at ways to do that and couldn't find a solution, also I can't mess up the data in production

Comment: I didn't read that there is a production database. I would still go with this approach and use the baseline property specifically for production. If it is easier to setup, as an alternative run the application locally and copy over the flyway_schema_history table (with the entry for the executed script) over to production, so no baseline is needed.

Comment: the baseline property isn't working though, thats the problem, some how i need to tell flyway its on version 9

Comment: I think it's supposed to be baselineVersionAsString property. But I couldn't find reliable information in the web, so maybe copying over the history table is a quicker option.

Answer (score 0):

Just try once after adding the following line in your application.yml
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate: true